# Reading a flat buffer always gives a EOF Exception after last line

Tags: eofexception, flatbuffers

Here is the code i have for reading a flat buffer file. I always get a EOF exception . How do i get rid of that exception...

```
  File file = new   File("/Users/samarnath/RmsOne/CreateFlatBuffer/src/com/rms/objects/SingleCoverRiskPolicy.fb");
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    int size;
    byte[] data = new byte[0];

    while ((randomAccessFile.read(data, 0, 0)) != -1)
    {
        try {
            size = randomAccessFile.readInt();
            data = new byte[size];
            randomAccessFile.read(data, 0, size);

            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            SingleCoverRiskPolicy singleCoverRiskPolicy = SingleCoverRiskPolicy.getRootAsSingleCoverRiskPolicy(bb);
            System.out.println(singleCoverRiskPolicy.id());

        } catch (EOFException e) {

            randomAccessFile.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am confused by your code... First off, `byte[] data = new byte[0];` doesn't have any use because you overwrite it later. Secondly, you are creating the `new RandomAccessFile()` outside of the try-catch. Third, you seem to be passing in `0` for the length of bytes to `randomAccessFile.read(buffer, offset, length)`. If you had meaning for any of these, please comment to clarify.

If you look at the Java Test file, they have an example you can reference: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/JavaTest.java#L30

Try something like this:

*Note: I did not compile this code. But it should be similar enough to address your issues.

```
File file = new File("/Users/samarnath/RmsOne/CreateFlatBuffer/src/com/rms/objects/SingleCoverRiskPolicy.fb");
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
byte[] data = null;

try {
    randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    data = new byte[(int)randomAccessFile.length()];
    randomAccessFile.readFully(data);
    randomAccessFile.close();
} catch(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(java.io.IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
} catch(java.lang.SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
} // Note: You can clean up these exceptions as needed (depending on your Java version).

// You're done reading it, now convert to a ByteBuffer and begin using.
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
SingleCoverRiskPolicy singleCoverRiskPolicy = SingleCoverRiskPolicy.getRootAsSingleCoverRiskPolicy(bb);
System.out.println(singleCoverRiskPolicy.id());
```